# What is the Different between HttpPost and HttpPut ? in Web Api

Tags: http, asp.net-web-api

**In CRUD Operations**

Many People use **[HttpPost]** to  ( Add, Update , Delete ) .

So : When we use **[HttpPost]** , **[HttpPut]** , **[HttpDelete]** and what is the Different .?

Answer (score 2):

To make it simple :

- POST = create
- PUT = update (more precisely, full update. For a partial update, use PATCH)
- DELETE = delete

More on that here : https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html

Comment: Any reasons for the downvote ?

Comment: I would be interrested in the reason too, to improve the answer.